# Type encapsulation in Coq

Tags: types, module, encapsulation, coq

Is there a way in which I can define a type inside a Coq module but encapsulate the constructors?

I want a client of the module to be capable to use the type but not to construct members of that type, similar to what can be done in OCaml with an abstract type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can define your type inside a module and assign a module type to it:

```
Module Type FOO.

Variable t : Type.

End FOO.

Module Foo : FOO.

Inductive typ :=
| T : typ.

Definition t := typ.

End Foo.

(* This fails *)
Check Foo.T.
```

Another possibility is to declare your module type as a dependent record and parameterize your development over a suitable implementation, e.g.

```
Record FOO := { t : Type }.

Section Defs.

Variable Foo : FOO.

(* Code ... *)

End Defs.

(* Instantiate FOO *)

Definition Foo := {| t := nat |}.
```

Strictly speaking, this doesn't hide the constructors of a type, but as long as your client is only writing their definitions using the interface, they won't be able to refer to your concrete implementation.